# How to hide a specific schema in the Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've implemented the Swagger Documentation in a web API made with C# (.NET Core 5).

I have 3 classes: `DefaultCommandResult`, `SuccessCommandResult` and `ErrorCommandResult`.

The `DefaultCommandResult` is the base class witch the other two inherit from. The object returned in the endpoint is either a `SuccessCommandResult` or `ErrorCommandResult`, and `DefaultCommandResult` is never returned.
What I need to do is hide the schema generated in the endpoints' responses related to the base class `DefaultCommandResult`:
[image: Swagger UI]

The request in the controller:

```
public ActionResult<DefaultCommandResult<ServerIdCommand>> Get([FromQuery] RecoverServerIdCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        var id = handler.RecoverServerId(command);

        if (id is null)
            return NotFound();

        var output = new ServerIdCommand { Id = id };
        var result = new SuccessCommandResult<ServerIdCommand>(output);

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex)
    {
        var result = new ErrorCommandResult<string>(ex.Message);
        return NotFound(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var result = new ErrorCommandResult<string>(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(result);
    }
}
```

The `DefaultCommandResult` class:

```
[SwaggerSubType(typeof(SuccessCommandResult<object>))]
[SwaggerSubType(typeof(ErrorCommandResult<object>))]
    
public class DefaultCommandResult<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    protected DefaultCommandResult(bool success)
    {
        Success = success;
    }
}
```

The `SuccessCommandResult` class (`ErrorCommandResult` follows the same structure, but for errors):

```
[SwaggerDiscriminator("successCommandResult")]
public class SuccessCommandResult<T> : DefaultCommandResult<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> Data { get; private set; }

    public SuccessCommandResult() : base(true) { }

    public SuccessCommandResult(List<T> data) : base(true)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public SuccessCommandResult(T @object) : base(true)
    {
        if (Data is null)
            Data = new List<T> { @object };
        else
            Data.Add(@object);
    }

}
```

How can I achieve that using the `Swashbuckle` framework for C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `[Produces(typeof(YourResponseModel)]` to specify what's the response for your API.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include (a sketch of) the C# code behind your controller action

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer with that info.

Comment: I am facing same problem in nestjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found a resolution for that was creating a Document Filter for the name of the schema:

```
public class SchemaNameFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    // w/o the filter: ServerIdCommandSuccessCommandResult. / with the filter: SuccessComandResult
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var schema in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
        {
            foreach (var schemaRepository in context.SchemaRepository.Schemas)
            {
                if (schema.Key.Equals(schemaRepository.Key))
                {
                    switch (schema.Key)
                    {
                        case string x when !x.Equals(nameof(DefaultCommandResult)) && x.Contains(nameof(DefaultCommandResult)):
                            schema.Value.Title = nameof(DefaultCommandResult);
                            break;
                        case string x when !x.Equals(nameof(SuccessCommandResult<string>)) && x.Contains(nameof(SuccessCommandResult<string>)):
                            schema.Value.Title = nameof(SuccessCommandResult<string>);
                            break;
                        case string a when !a.Equals(nameof(OutputCommandResult)) && a.Contains(nameof(OutputCommandResult)):
                            schema.Value.Title = nameof(OutputCommandResult);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

What it does, basically, is rename the Swagger schema (with the incorrect name) to the name of the class.

Then, in the `Startup` class, add the document filter:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
{
   c.DocumentFilter<SchemaNameFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Hidden` from  `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden`